# Manipulating rows of a dataframe that exist in another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing all my training, validation and test data. And a dataframe containing my test data only. The datapoints are specified by 'data_index'.

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame({'data_index': range(7), 'split': 'NA'})
df_all.set_index('data_index', inplace=True)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'data_index': [3, 5], 'split': 'test'})
df_test.set_index('data_index', inplace=True)



           split
data_index      
0             NA
1             NA
2             NA
3             NA
4             NA
5             NA
6             NA

           split
data_index      
3           test
5           test
```

how do I fill in the values of 'split' column in the first dataframe based on the test dataframe? In order to get something like this:

```
                split
data_index           
0           train/val
1           train/val
2           train/val
3                test
4           train/val
5                test
6           train/val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df_all['split'] = df_all.index.map(df_test['split'].get)
df_all['split']= df_all['split'].fillna('train/val') 
print (df_all)
                split
data_index           
0           train/val
1           train/val
2           train/val
3                test
4           train/val
5                test
6           train/val
```

If there are missing values use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
#defined np.nan for missing values, not string NA
df_all = pd.DataFrame({'data_index': range(7), 'split': np.nan})
df_all.set_index('data_index', inplace=True)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'data_index': [3, 5], 'split': 'test'})
df_test.set_index('data_index', inplace=True)

df_all['split'] = df_all['split'].combine_first(df_test['split']).fillna('train/val') 
print (df_all)
                split
data_index           
0           train/val
1           train/val
2           train/val
3                test
4           train/val
5                test
6           train/val
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Index.map as explained above, the problem could be solved using some basic concepts with the following approach as well:

```
df = pd.merge(df_all, df_test, how='left', on='data_index')
df.drop(['split_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'split_y': 'split'})
df.loc[df.split != 'test', 'split'] = 'train/val'
```

The result following each line is:

```
          split_x split_y
data_index                
0               NA     NaN
1               NA     NaN
2               NA     NaN
3               NA    test
4               NA     NaN
5               NA    test
6               NA     NaN

           split_y
data_index        
0              NaN
1              NaN
2              NaN
3             test
4              NaN
5             test
6              NaN

           split
data_index      
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3           test
4            NaN
5           test
6            NaN

                split
data_index           
0           train/val
1           train/val
2           train/val
3                test
4           train/val
5                test
6           train/val
```